# AWS: There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I am running a `64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.5.2 running Tomcat 8 Java 8` environment on `AWS Elasticbeanstalk` free tier (Instance type: `t1.micro`).

I have a number of RESTful services, when one particular service is called, that does some work, I consistently get a `502 error`, and the following in the logs:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:
>   os::commit_memory(0x00000000e2220000, 130215936, 0) failed;
>   error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>    Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 130215936 bytes for committing reserved memory.
>    An error report file with more information is saved as:
>    /tmp/hs_err_pid31500.log OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=64m; support was removed in 8.0

**Question**

Does this mean I need to upgrade to a payed version, i.e. greater than Instance type: `t1.micro`?

Or, is there a way I can configure my environment to handle this?

The reason I ask, is because the logs above indicate that the Java App is requiring only `130mb` (`130215936 bytes`) of memory, where below you can see the `JVM heap` size is a lot larger. So I would not have expected it to fall over at `130mb`.

**More Info**

I do have the following configurations settings:

[image]

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I change the `Max JVM` to `256mb`, but still get the error:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m;
>   support was removed in 8.0 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:
>   os::commit_memory(0x00000000c0000000, 89456640, 0) failed;
>   error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>    Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 89456640 bytes for committing reserved memory.
>    An error report file with more information is saved as:
>    /tmp/hs_err_pid14014.log OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

But here it falls over on only `89mb`.

Comment: Are you sure there's enough memory in your instance to handle the heap size you're requesting? Try changing max jvm heap size to something smaller

Comment: give us the output of your memory stat. use top or htop, etc.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that in an AWS environment. As far as I know, I don't have access to a command line. Or do I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message in your update, it seems like you tried to adjust the JVM permanent generation size. Try to leave this setting to whatever the default is. Instead, set both the initial and the maximum heap size to 64mb.

If it is still crashing, once it crashed, you can ssh to the AWS instance and look at what is using the memory. In beanstalk, in the configurations of your environment, under "Instances", you can select the keypair you want to use with your instances. You can find the instances launched by beanstalk in the EC2 console, like any other instance.

Comment: Thanks.  I know the code that is causing the crash. I am doing some word chunking to get the nouns out of a sentence. It runs fine on my localhost, but falls over on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. But what surprised me was that it is not using much memory as reported in the log files (130mb).  I will set the initial and maximum heap size to 64mb, and see what happens.

Comment: After adjusting the initial and maximum heap size to 64mb, I get: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: @Richard ok, so now it's your java process that's running out of memory. Try progressively increasing your initial/max memory. Try 128mb and 256mb. If you go back to having the machine running out of memory, login to the instance and look what's using the rest of the memory. If once reaching 256mb heap size you still get the java OutOfMemoryError, then I think you won't be able to use t2.micro.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's what I am trying to establish, do I need to upgrade my AWS service, or can I get it working on my current "free" (t1.micro) service.  Do you know how much memory a t1.micro server has available? I read here, it's 0.613GB, so not sure why it falls over at 130mb.  http://www.ec2instances.info/

Comment: At initial JVM heap size of 128m and Maximum JVM heap of 256m, I get ava.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Comment: You should probably use t2.micro btw. It is the next generation of t.micro instances and those are included as part of the free tier. (I don't even know if t1.micro are still eligible for the free tier). T2.micro have 1gb of memory

Comment: Thank you for the advise.  I will have a look at t2.micro.